# Descargar blob google docs desde app script con javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

tengo una plantilla en google docs, y estoy intentando descargarla en el cliente mediante javascript,
el problema es que el `blob` del doc lo paso como un `array` y no se guarda correctamente al descargarse, lo que me genera un error al abrirlo.

En appscript utilizo:

```
function test(){  
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById("xxxx")       
  let archivo = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  let attach = {fileName:doc.getName() + ".pdf",content:archivo, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
  return attach;
}
```

`archivo` tiene la forma: Array(80856)

En el cliente utilizo:

```
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(file => {
        console.log(file)
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";

        let blob = new Blob(file.content, {mimeType:'application/pdf'});                        
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = file.fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    
  }).test();
```

El `console.log` muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error al abrir el ARCHIVO PDF

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es del cliente o server (app script)?
Es el blob que envio o la descarga erronea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre la solucion en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033128/serve-pdf-file-as-blob-in-google-apps-script)

La funcion del server:

```
function test(){  
      const doc = DocumentApp.openById("xxxx")       
      let archivo = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
      let encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(archivo.getBytes());
      let attach = {fileName:doc.getName() + ".pdf",content:encoded};
    
      return attach;   
    }
```

La funcion del cliente:

```
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(file => {
 
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";

        a.href = "data:application/pdf;base64," + file.content;
        a.download = file.fileName;
        a.click();
    
  }).test();
```